# Parse server and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: parse-platform, google-cloud-storage, parse-server

Hi I got the parse server running in Google cloud platform. I am using MLab for database and Google cloud storage as File adapter.

I am able to upload small files which are 1 mb to 5 mb and I can see them in GCS.
 However I am not able to upload large files like more than 10 MB. I have the GCS free tier for 5 GB. Is there any file upload limit for parse server ?

Update : I was able to tweak the maxUploadSize in Parse server to 500 mb. I am able to upload files like 30mb. But still not able to upload large files.

Comment: i am having same problem.  Even after updating maxUploadSize to '500mb' i can still only upload less than 40mb.  Did you ever get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your VM instance you need to also set the Apache2 or Nginx to allow for greater size.

Nginx:

```
client_max_body_size
```

Apache2:

Check the make sure that `LimitRequestBody` is not set. By default this should be zero (unlimited)

Parse-server:

```
maxUploadSize
```

Comment: Tks. But I using Google Cloud Storage here. I already increased the maxUploadSize to 500mb, still I am not able to upload large files like 100mb. Is there any limitation to the parse-server or parse-server-dashboard ?

Comment: No other limitations. Are you running nginx in your vm?

Comment: Nope.  I am using this setup https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/frameworks/parse-server#parse-serverjs_config.